# Об употреблении слов "либо", "хотеть", "ежели", "если", "а", "не"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама и валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери туза." означает указание с условием "Ежели ты хочешь взять туза, тогда возьми туза.",
- указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери туза." означает указание с условием "Ежели ты не хочешь брать туза, тогда не бери туза.",
- указание с условием "Ежели ты хочешь взять туза, тогда возьми туза." означает указание с условием "Если ты хочешь взять туза, тогда возьми туза; а если ты не хочешь брать туза, тогда не бери туза."?

P.S. Этот вопрос сформулирован благодаря ответу участника Серж на один из моих предыдущих вопросов.

Answer (score 2):

Робот отдыхает сразу,при этом на мониторе появляется  странная запись: No information.

Answer (score 0):

Указание "Либо возьми туза, либо не бери туза." **может означать** указание с условием, причём любым условием, как прямым, так и инвертированным, поскольку условие не указано явным образом.

Comment: Это все тот же.

Comment: У Галактиона очень строгая логика в этих булевых вопросах. Машинная логика. Чем и интересно.

Comment: Я на английском ответил на десяток подробных вопросов от него. Потом перестал. Ему стало скучно - он приполз на русский с этой логикой". Моё дело предупредить. Если кому-то нравится отвечать, то ради бога. Только не уходите от русского слишком даладеко в сторону этой "логики". Естественный язык - штука не логичная..  .))))

Comment: С последним утверждением упаси Бог меня спорить))). 
Если у него родной английский, то тяжеленько ему будет, не разберётся. Инглиш не зря ареал большинства языков программирования, он легче поддаётся формализации.

Comment: Родной у него - феня))) Я на английском ***форуме*** с ним общался. На вполне  русском языке объяснял, сколько нужно запятых ставить после одного английского слова. Английский выбран в программировании потому, что это язык международного общения и  потому, что это родной для большинства разработчиков и продуктов. Были "русские" разработки, "Рапира", например. Но они оказались мертворожденными и невостребованными.  .

Comment: Да и пряное растение с ним. Меня привлекла занимательность подхода. Серия вопросов  о союзах - чистые задачи на булеву алгебру. Может, он так гуманитариев троллит.
Рапиру помню, как же. Калька Бэйсика. ДРАКОН мне больше нравится )))